# How to detect and measure(fitEllipse) objects on the SEM image using OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have about 30 SEM (scanning-electron microscope) images like that:

[image]

What you see is photoresist pillars on a glass substrate. 
What I would like to do, is to get the mean diameter in x and y-direction as well as the mean period in x- and y-direction.

Now, instead of doing all the measurement manually, I was wondering, if maybe there is a way to **automate it using python and opencv** ?

EDIT:
I tried the following code, it seems to be *working to detect circles*, **but what I actually need are ellipse,** since I need the diameter in x- and y-direction.

... and I don't quite see how to get the scale yet ?

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread("01.jpg",0)
output = img.copy()

edged = cv2.Canny(img, 10, 300)
edged = cv2.dilate(edged, None, iterations=1)
edged = cv2.erode(edged, None, iterations=1)



# detect circles in the image
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(edged, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.2, 100)


# ensure at least some circles were found
if circles is not None:
    # convert the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles to integers
    circles = np.round(circles).astype("int")

    # loop over the (x, y) coordinates and radius of the circles
    for (x, y, r) in circles[0]:
        print(x,y,r)
        # draw the circle in the output image, then draw a rectangle
        # corresponding to the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(output, (x, y), r, (0, 255, 0), 4)
        cv2.rectangle(output, (x - 5, y - 5), (x + 5, y + 5), (0, 128, 255), -1)

    # show the output image
    plt.imshow(output, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
    plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])  # to hide tick values on X and Y axis
    plt.figure()
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Source of inspiration: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/07/21/detecting-circles-images-using-opencv-hough-circles/

Comment: Some pre-processing would probably help. First of all, I'd cut off that text area at the bottom. Identify all the big bright blobs. Partition the image into ROIs, such that each ROI contains only one blob. Discard the ROIs that contain partial blobs (i.e. where the blob is near the edge). Do further analysis on the remaining ROIs. (Oh, and kudos for not using JPEG for the input image)

Comment: Since you mention ellipse, you can do `cv2.fitEllipse` on the contours of the pillars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I rarely find Hough useful for realworld applications, thus I'd rather follow the path of denoising, segmentation and ellipse fit.

For the denoising, one selects the non local means (NLM). For the segmentation --- just looking at the image --- I came up with a Gaussian mixture model with three classes: one for background and two for the object (diffuse and specular component). Here, the mixture model essentially models the shape of the graylevel image histogram by three Gaussian functions (as demonstrated in [Wikipedia mixture-histogram gif](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Movie.gif)). Interested reader is redirected to [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_model).

Ellipse fit at the end is just an elementary OpenCV-tool.

In C++, but in analogue to OpenCV-Python

```
#include "opencv2/ml.hpp"
#include "opencv2/photo.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
void gaussianMixture(const cv::Mat &src, cv::Mat &dst, int nClasses )
{
    if ( src.type()!=CV_8UC1 )
        CV_Error(CV_StsError,"src is not 8-bit grayscale");

    // reshape
    cv::Mat samples( src.rows * src.cols, 1, CV_32FC1 );
    src.convertTo( cv::Mat( src.size(), CV_32FC1, samples.data ), CV_32F );

    cv::Mat labels;
    cv::Ptr<cv::ml::EM> em = cv::ml::EM::create();
    em->setClustersNumber( nClasses );
    em->setTermCriteria( cv::TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 4, 0.0 ) );
    em->trainEM( samples );

    if ( dst.type()!=CV_8UC1 || dst.size()!=src.size() )
        dst = cv::Mat( src.size(),CV_8UC1 );
    for(int y=0;y<src.rows;++y)
    {
        for(int x=0;x<src.cols;++x)
        {
            dst.at<unsigned char>(y,x) = em->predict( src.at<unsigned char>(y,x) );
        }
    }
}
void automate()
{
    cv::Mat input = cv::imread( /* input image in color */,cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
    cv::Mat inputDenoised;
    cv::fastNlMeansDenoising( input, inputDenoised, 8.0, 5, 17 );
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(inputDenoised,gray,cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY );
    gaussianMixture(gray,gray,3 );

    typedef std::vector< std::vector< cv::Point > >  VecOfVec;
    VecOfVec contours;
    cv::Mat objectPixels = gray>0;
    cv::findContours( objectPixels, contours, cv::RETR_LIST, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_NONE );
    cv::Mat inputcopy; // for drawing of ellipses
    input.copyTo( inputcopy );
    for ( size_t i=0;i<contours.size();++i )
    {
        if ( contours[i].size() < 5 )
            continue;
        cv::drawContours( input, VecOfVec{contours[i]}, -1, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2 );
        cv::RotatedRect rect = cv::fitEllipse( contours[i] );
        cv::ellipse( inputcopy, rect, cv::Scalar(0,0,255), 2 );
    }
}
```

I should have cleaned the very small contours (in upper row second) (larger than the minimum 5 points) before drawing ellipses.

*** edit *** 
added Python predictor without the denoising and find-contours part. After learning the model, the time to predict is about 1.1 second

```
img = cv.imread('D:/tmp/8b3Lm.jpg', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE )

class Predictor :
    def train( self, img ):
        self.em = cv.ml.EM_create()
        self.em.setClustersNumber( 3 )
        self.em.setTermCriteria( ( cv.TERM_CRITERIA_COUNT,4,0 ) )
        samples = np.reshape( img, (img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], -1) ).astype('float')
        self.em.trainEM( samples )

    def predict( self, img ):
        samples = np.reshape( img, (img.shape[0]*img.shape[1], -1) ).astype('float')
        labels = np.zeros( samples.shape, 'uint8' )
        for i in range ( samples.shape[0] ):
            retval, probs = self.em.predict2( samples[i] )
            labels[i] = retval[1] * (255/3) # make it [0,255] for imshow
        return np.reshape( labels, img.shape )

predictor = Predictor()

predictor.train( img )
t = time.perf_counter()
predictor.train( img )
t = time.perf_counter() - t
print ( "train %s s" %t )

t = time.perf_counter()
labels = predictor.predict( img )
t = time.perf_counter() - t
print ( "predict %s s" %t )

cv.imshow( "prediction", labels  )
cv.waitKey( 0 )
```

[image: Denoised]
[image: Contours]
[image: Ellipses]
[image: Mixture of Gaussians]

Comment: Nice. Could you, perhaps, add some information on how the `gaussianMixture` works? (BTW, the input is grayscale, so you could read it as such and skip the `cvtColor` -- you won't get color from an electron microscope).

Comment: @DanMašek, I wanted to draw in color, so either way, I had to use `cvtColor` :)

Comment: Right... doh :D Thanks for the extra info. I guess in this case, this is akin to a k-means clustering? (I'll have to read through it it more detail later)

Comment: Very nice answer, but can you also extract the major and minor ellipse axis length in x-and y- direction ?

Comment: @james the axes of the ellipse in the rotated frame are readily read in `cv::RotatedRect`s `size` member (`a=size.width/2.0` etc.). If you want to calculate the bounding box in the image frame, you can follow the equation in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91132/how-to-get-the-limits-of-rotated-ellipse

Comment: Also, if you have a consistent imaging setup, you can learn the mixture model only once and just call `predict` for next frames

Comment: @mainactual I do have a consistent imaging setup, so this would be a good option.However I am not an expert in C++. Do you know how to write this code in Python ?

Comment: @james, added a Python-predictor, you can fill the caps by copying from the other answer

Comment: @mainactual Thanks a lot !! Sorry for the late reply, somehow I missed your comment...

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the `HoughCircles` method, from openCV. It will give you all the circles in the image. Then it will be easy to compute the radius and the position of each circles.

Look at : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html

Comment: Thanks for that note ! I will check it out. :)

Comment: Do you know how to detect ellipses ?

Comment: The `skimage.transform` package has a hough_ellipse function but I never used it.

Answer (score 0):

I use `cv2.ml.EM` to segment the image first in OpenCV (Python), it costs about `13 s`. If just `fitEllipse` on the contours of the threshed image, it costs `5 ms`, the the result maybe not that accurate. Just a tradeoff.

[image]

---

Details:

> 1. Convert into grayscale and threshed it
> 2. Morph to denoise
> 3. Find the external contours
> 4. Fit ellipses

---

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2019/02/13 
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/54604608/54661984

import cv2
import numpy as np

fpath = "sem.png"
img = cv2.imread(fpath)

## Convert into grayscale and threshed it
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
th, threshed = cv2.threshold(gray, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

## Morph to denoise
threshed = cv2.dilate(threshed, None)
threshed = cv2.erode(threshed, None)

## Find the external contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(threshed, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)[-2]
cv2.drawContours(img, cnts, -1, (255, 0, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

## Fit ellipses
for cnt in cnts:
    if cnt.size < 10 or cv2.contourArea(cnt) < 100:
        continue

    rbox = cv2.fitEllipse(cnt)
    cv2.ellipse(img, rbox, (255, 100, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)

## This it
cv2.imwrite("dst.jpg", img)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you extract the major and minor ellipse axis ?